# Python embedded in HTML returns error when there is no input

Tags: python, html

I've written this code:

> http://pastebin.com/e3aZzqVB

loading from this page:

> nimasa.heliohost.org/RJ/

The problem comes from no-input which returns error, although there is no problem on interpreter as it could be seen at:

> repl.it/v88/2

Waiting for your suggestions,

What should I change/or add/ to make it not to return error on no-input?

Thanks,

Nima

Comment: "The problem comes from no-input which returns error" : are we supposed to guess what "error" it "returns" ? Please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form.getvalue("b")` will return `None` if there's no value for `b` in the request. Trying to slice `None` (at line 19 : `s = b[35:]`) - or to apply any string method or function FWIW - will (obviously) raise a `TypeError`.

For the record, it took me about 30 seconds to find out:

```
# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cgi
>>> f = cgi.FieldStorage()
>>> f.getvalue("foo") is None
True
```

Comment: You're right - but even though I changed like this:
http://pastebin.com/yTyp6bh2
I'm getting "Internal server error" when submitting with no input.

Comment: And the reason is quite obvious... Please let met quote myself : "Trying to (...) apply any string method or function (to None) will (obviously) raise a TypeError". Hint: `None` is NOT an empty string. While we're at it, may I suggest you read the first paragraphs of the cgi module's documentation ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#using-the-cgi-module

Comment: Thank you very much bruno desthuilliers, the documentation was helpful.


I did it like this: 

`if form.getvalue("b") is not None:`

Comment: like this: `if form.getvalue("b") is not None and form.getvalue("b")[12:22].lower()  in ["radiojavan", "diojavan.c"]:`

Comment: If you found the doc usefull, keep on using it : `FieldStorage.getvalue()` works just like `dict.get()`, so you can pass an (optional) default value as second argument. IOW: just replacing `b = form.getvalue("b")` with `b = form.getvalue("b", "")` would have solved your problem...

Comment: Thank a lot bruno desthuilliers.